# Mapbox-Gl-Draw: Cannot set property 'modes' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I am trying to initialize a MapboxDraw object with the following JS code:

```
var graphicsController = MapboxDraw(); // Initialize the graphics controller
```

I am importing mapbox-gl-draw w/ the following CDN:

```
<script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-draw/v1.0.9/mapbox-gl-draw.js'></script>
```

However I get the following error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'modes' of undefined
>   (mapbox-gl-draw.js:1)

What does this mean? Is it some bug of mapbox-gl-draw that I can just ignore or do I need to do anything to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MapboxDraw` is a constructor, so you need to initialize it with **new** keyword:

```
var graphicsController = new MapboxDraw();
```